# How to use javascript split function in this case

Tags: javascript

I have a Name Value pair returned from Javascript array which will be in this format

```
var priceData = [[0,100.34],[1,108.31],[2,109.40],[3,104.87],[4,106.00]]
```

I need the last element in that array , so i used this way

```
var result = priceData[priceData.length-1];

alert(result);
```

But i am getting result as **4,106.00**

I want to get only the 106.00 (That is the last elemenet)

Please tell me , how to do this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's another array, so index the `1`-th element:

```
var result = priceData[priceData.length-1][1];
```

Comment: this code gives you the second element in that array not the last. just that in this example the second item happens to be the last.

Answer (score 2):

```
> x=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]

> x.slice(-1)[0]
[5,6]

> x.slice(-1)[0].slice(-1)[0]
6
```

alternatively:

```
> x.slice(-1)[0][1]
6
```

Comment: x.slice(-1)[0].slice(-1)[0] = 6

Answer (score 1):

The last element of your array is indeed [4, 106.00].
The last element of the last element of your array is 106.00

Answer (score 1):

```
var priceData = [[0,100.34],[1,108.31],[2,109.40],[3,104.87],[4,106.00]]
var result = priceData[priceData.length-1];
alert(result[result.length-1]);
```